# Laravel and Modals: Passing unique @foreach value into modal form?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, modal-dialog

I have a list of job postings on a page. For each posting, I have a button called 'send to a friend'. Clicking the button pulls up a modal with a form where you can input your friend's email, and submit the form.

How can I pull the related job posting name to my form? {{$posting->name}}

**Job postings page:**

```
@foreach ($postings as $posting)

                  <a href="postings/{{ $posting->id }}"> <p> {{ $posting-> short_desc }} </p> </a>
                  <p> {{ $posting->location }} | {{ $posting->duration }} </p>

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" href="postings/sendfriend" value="{{ $posting->short_desc }}" data-target="#sendfriend" style="background-color: #004AAE; color: #FFF; font-family: Lato; border-radius: 10px;">Send to a friend</button>

@endforeach

@include('postings.sendfriend')
```

**Modal:**

```
<div id="sendfriend" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">


<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Invite a friend to apply for this rotation</h4>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-body">  
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ action('FriendController@store') }}">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter friend's email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline"> Share the love </button>

</div></div>
</form></div></div>
```

**Friend controller:**

```
public function store() {
  $friend = new Friend;
  $friend->email = request('email');
  $friend->company = $posting->name; //Something like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the posting id to your modal button

```
<button type="button" data-id="{{ $posting->id }}" class="btn btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" href="postings/sendfriend" value="{{ $posting->short_desc }}" data-target="#sendfriend" style="background-color: #004AAE; color: #FFF; font-family: Lato; border-radius: 10px;">Send to a friend</button>
```

in your modal form create a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="posting">
```

Use the following js to pass the posting id to the hidden filed

```
$('#sendfriend').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var id = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body input[name="posting"]').val(id);
})
```

Get the id in the controller

```
$friend->company = request('posting');
```